# Windows 7 leave it on GENERAL ITEMS

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'm tired of changing the view in Windows 7 back to "General Items" every time someone drops a media file in there.

Is there a way to STOP Windows 7 explorer from changing the view from General Items to Music or whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires a registry hack.  You need to turn disable the "autodiscovery" feature

1. In Registry Editor (regedit), navigate to the following registry branch:
     HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell
2. Right click on Shell in left pane, select New and then click Key.
3. Type Bags to create a key named Bags, and press Enter.
4. Right click on Bags that just been created, select New and then click Key.
5. Type AllFolders to create a sub-key named AllFolders, and and press Enter.
6. Right click on AllFolders that just been created, select New and then click Key.
7. Type Shell to create another subkey named Shell, and then press Enter.
8. Select Shell key that just been created, and then right click on an empty area in the right pane, click on New and then select String Value.
9. Type FolderType as the value name, and press Enter.
10. Right click on the Folder Type and click Modify or simply double click on FolderType.
11. Type NotSpecified as its value data.
12. Click OK.

From this [Win forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-explorer-column-heading-permanent/0273d101-b336-4228-a82b-52b3d102628d) post.

Answer (score 1):

Next time it does it, change the view to what you need, then go to Tools > Folder Options > View Tab, hit the apply to folders button.

.
[image]

.
[image]

.

Comment: This is wrong because Windows will go and change it

Comment: Then you have something else wrong with the system (registry).

Comment: Really?  Are you sure?  The `autodiscovery` feature seems to be the guilty party

Comment: No one is ever sure until they actually solve the problem. Everything in Windows is based on the registry to work properly, in my experience weird problems are always found to be registry problems.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a default viewing template to any folder and all its subfolders. First, you need to select the best viewing template for the current folder and its subfolders. Then, you can configure the way you view its contents (details view, icons views, etc.)
After that, you can apply the view you just configured to the viewing template. That way it will get applied to all folders sharing the same viewing template.

Detailed steps can be found in this tutorial: [Configure the Default Viewing Templates in Windows Explorer to be as YOU Want Them!](http://www.7tutorials.com/configure-default-viewing-templates-windows-explorer-be-you-want-them)

Comment: This is wrong because Windows will go and change it